# android app icon missing on certain device

Tags: android

I've recently developed an Android app. For some reason the app icon does not show on the home screen on a HTC One device. The icon shows fine for my other devices.

Reading other forums, I have made sure the app is stored within the phone rather than the SD card, and tried rebooting but these do not seem to fix the issue.

I'm guessing that the HTC One is not picking up the icon file, but I'm not sure why - as the other devices including Galaxsy S3 and other HTC devices do? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you've created folders to support various densities? ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi? If that's the case, are you sure you've put your icon in XHDPI folder because HTC ONE will read it from there because it has very big density.

For example:

According to [GSM Arena, Galaxy S3](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9300_galaxy_s_iii-4238.php) Galaxy S3 has 306ppi pixel density. That's high density and this phone will read drawables from hdpi folder.

On the other hand, HTC ONE has 469ppi pixel density. That's extra large density and this phone will read drawables from x-hdpi folder. [GSM Arena, HTC ONE](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_one-5313.php)

But this may not be the case, because if drawable is missing from one folder will just read it from another available. But please check again your x large folder.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! We had created the XHDPI folder but the icon in it had somehow been corrupted and was unreadable. Thanks again :-)